# Processing many, many rows quickly in R

Tags: r, performance

I'm trying to process data in R from two databases with the same number and name of columns and rows. One database (database1) has '1' and '--'s that dictate which cells are worth looking at.  The other database (database2) is just full of data.

I'm trying to replace all 'worthless data' (marked by a '--' in database1) in database2 with '--' as well.

My code works well, but it's really, really slow. Granted there are 1900 rows and ~8000 columns in each spreadsheet, the code is taking about 4+ hours to run, which is suboptimal.

How could I make this code faster? Anything helps!
THANKS!!

Here's the code (pardon for the variable names :P ):

```
for (n in 1:nrow(poopy)){
 list <- 0
 gooddates <- colnames(additions[which(additions[n,] == ' 1 ' | additions[n,] == '1')]) #some cells have a '1' and others a ' 1 ', so this accounts for both.
 for (j in 1:length(gooddates)){
   nextdateindex <- which(gooddates[j] == colnames(additions))+1  #database1 is by month. database2 is by day, so I'm taking the intervals of gooddates.
   if (is.na(colnames(additions)[nextdateindex])){
     nextdateindex <- '6.26.2014'
     couple <- cbind(gooddates[j], nextdateindex) #start and end intervals of gooddates
     list <- rbind(list, couple)
   }
   else{
     couple <- cbind(gooddates[j], colnames(additions)[nextdateindex])
     list <- rbind(list, couple)
   }
 }
 list <- list[-1,]

test <- poopy

if (is.null(nrow(list))){  ##some lists will only have one interval. this changes the indexing for some reason.
test <- test[n,-which(colnames(test) == list[1]):-(which(colnames(test) == list[2])-1)]
}
 else{
for (i in 1:nrow(list)){
  test <- test[n,-which(colnames(test) == list[i,1]):-(which(colnames(test) == list[i,2])-1)]
}
}

 poopy[n,which((test == "--") == FALSE)[-1]] <- '--'

}
```

EDIT: Database1 is monthly and database2 is daily, so 1s and --s can't be matched one to one from database1 to database2. I am assuming that the 1s in database 1 remain a 1 for the entire month, which is why I'm doing a range in the 'couple' variable that takes the date in database1 as the first column name, and nextdateindex the day before the next datapoint in Database1.  Hope this clarifies it!

Quite close, Roland. Thanks for the try!

Comment: Can you include an sample dataset for poopy? If the data is not sensitive do `dput(head(poopy, 10))`

Comment: Nothing fancy. Dataset1 has -- and 1s. Dataset 2 has numbers. The difference is that Dataset1 has columns for months and dataset2 has columns for all days, so number of columns differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without input data, but maybe something like this:

```
#some artificial data
set.seed(42)
dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), 5))
dat2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1, "--"),20, TRUE), 5))

#a one-liner
dat1[dat2=="1"] <- NA
dat1
#          V1          V2         V3         V4
# 1        NA -0.10612452         NA  0.6359504
# 2        NA  1.51152200         NA -0.2842529
# 3        NA -0.09465904         NA         NA
# 4 0.6328626  2.01842371 -0.2787888         NA
# 5        NA -0.06271410         NA  1.3201133
```

Note how I use `NA` instead of `"--"` in the result as R has many facilities to deal with `NA` values, which those seem to be in your data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a new null table with the dates and rownames of database2, called additions2. I then selected the valid columns in database1 with data and copied the previously valid row all the way across until the next valid row, like this:

```
additions2 <- additions2[order(additions2$Security.Name),]

valid <- which(colnames(additions2) %in% intersect(colnames(additions2), colnames(additions)))

additions2[,valid] <- additions
valid <- valid[-1]

additions3 <- additions2
for (i in (2:length(valid)-1)){
  additions2[,valid[i]:(valid[i+1]-1)] <- additions[1+i]
}

additions22 <- additions2

additions22[,tail(valid,1):ncol(additions22)] <- additions[ncol(additions)]
```